# Wordpress comment_text() missing <p> tags

Tags: wordpress, post, format

I'm creating my own WordPress Bootstrap theme and have run in to a strange issue.

When I submit a comment and it's waiting for moderation, `comment_text()` does not output any `<p>` tags.

I've tried disabling all the plugins and renaming my `functions.php` file and the issue persists.

My code :

`<div class="comment-content my-4"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>`

Approved comment ( has `<p>` tags ):

```
<div id="comment-10" class="comment even thread-even depth-1  media">
<div class="d-flex mt-2 p-2 border rounded">
<div class="flex-grow-1 ms-3">
<div class="author">Barry says</div>
<div class="small"><a href="https://example.com/test/#comment-10" class="text-decoration-none">September 11, 2022 at 8:06 am</a></div>
<div class="comment-content my-4"><p>Testing to see how this comment looks</p></div>
```

Waiting for moderation ( no `<p>` tags ):

```
<div id="comment-59" class="comment even thread-even depth-1  media">
<div class="d-flex mt-2 p-2 border rounded">
<div class="flex-grow-1 ms-3">
<div class="author">Dave says</div>
<div class="small"><a href="https://example.com/test/#comment-59" class="text-decoration-none">October 5, 2022 at 8:14 pm</a></div>
<p class="card-text comment-awaiting-moderation label label-info text-muted">Your comment is awaiting moderation.</p>
<div class="comment-content my-4">ok how does this look</div>
```

Also, when I enable the subscribe to comments reloaded plugin, the comment looks like this :

```
<div id="comment-63" class="comment even thread-even depth-1  media">
<div class="d-flex mt-2 p-2 border rounded">
<div class="flex-grow-1 ms-3">
<div class="author">Ken says</div>
<div class="small"><a href="https://example.com/test/#comment-63" class="text-decoration-none">October 5, 2022 at 8:45 pm</a></div>
<p class="card-text comment-awaiting-moderation label label-info text-muted">Your comment is awaiting moderation.</p>
<div class="comment-content my-4">Check your email to confirm your subscription.
Ok this doesn't look right
</div>
```

Looking at the source code for the plugin, they also add `<p>` tags for their message, but those are getting removed as well.

I'm at a loss to what the issue could be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

The WordPress function `wp_kses` in `Walker_Comment::filter_comment_text()` strips all `<p>` tags by default (`<p>` tag is not listed in the "$allowedtags" array).

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L379-L413

To solve this issue, I only wanted to allow `<p>` tags in comments so I added the following function inside my `Bootstrap_Comment_Walker extends Walker_Comment` class :

```
public function filter_comment_text( $comment_text, $comment )
{
    $allowedtags = array(
            'p' => array(),
    );
    return wp_kses( $comment_text, $allowedtags );
}
```

Everything is working as expected now.